# xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65 is displaying when tried to start session with Appium Desktop

Tags: appium, appium-ios

When i tried to start session with appium desktop i am getting following error:

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.

Desired Capabilities Used in Appium Desktop:

```
{
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "deviceName": "iPhone 7",
  "udid": "93551a7d721b790b0188642402f1ada96892b816",
  "app": "/Users/globalit/Desktop/IntegrationApp.app",
  "automationName": "XCUITest",
  "noReset": true
}
```

Configuration:
IOS 11, OSX 10.12, Xcode 8.1, Appium Desktop 1.2.5

Error logs:

```
[Xcode] 2017-10-27 15:27:28.943 xcodebuild[871:24036] Error Domain=com.apple.platform.iphoneos Code=-12 "Unable to launch com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to launch com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd602a29400 {Error Domain=DTXMessage Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={DTXExceptionKey=The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to launch com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user. : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner'}}}
[Xcode] 2017-10-27 15:27:28.943 xcodebuild[871:24036] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=5 "Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted}
[Xcode] ** TEST EXECUTE FAILED **
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 
[XCUITest] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartFailed' logged at 1509098248985 (15:27:28 GMT+0530 (IST))
[XCUITest] Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
[XCUITest] Quitting and uninstalling WebDriverAgent, then retrying
[XCUITest] Shutting down sub-processes
[XCUITest] Shutting down iproxy process (pid 870)
[XCUITest] iproxy exited with code 'null'
[XCUITest] Removing WDA application from device
[XCUITest] Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
    at XCUITestDriver.quitAndUninstall$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:381:13)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
 Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
    at XCUITestDriver.quitAndUninstall$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:381:13)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
[XCUITest] Not clearing log files. Use `clearSystemFiles` capability to turn on.
[iOSLog] Stopping iOS log capture
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
    at XCUITestDriver.quitAndUninstall$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:381:13)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 29571 ms - 470 
[HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session {}
[HTTP] No route found. Setting content type to 'text/plain'
[HTTP] <-- DELETE /wd/hub/session 404 13 ms - 57
```

Answer (score 3):

Please run the Xcode project which is located here on your device once: `/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj`

And let me know if you face any problems.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue with Appium-desktop after upgrading to Xcode 12.4 and trying to run on ios 14.4, it worked for me after adding the following capabilities:
{
"xcodeOrgId": "OrgID",
"xcodeSigningId": "SignId",
}

i'm using appium-desktop 1.18.3

Answer (score 0):

`WebdriverAgent` is not built and tested in your mobile device. I faced the same issue and resolved it by getting the Webdriver agent to open in my mobile device.

Comment: Could you elaborate in your answer.  Provide a link or documentation to building WebdriverAgent or how to add it to the xcode build.

Answer (score 0):

The configs from Ashraf answer worked for me. I was facing this issue for more than 24 hours. I have similar configs, iPad with iOS 14.4 and Appium desktop 1.20.2 version, and XCode in 12.4 version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command on the terminal:

```
cd /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent
xcodebuild -allowProvisioningUpdates -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination 'id=Your Device UDID' test
```

Comment: Yes, this command helps me to install WDA on a device, but when I try to launch a test, WDA is deleted by Appium and I see a 65 error again and again.

I'm using `usePrebuiltWDA`, `updatedWDABundleId`, `useNewWDA`, `noReset` and other capabilities and nothing helps me. Just a 65 error meets me.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my appium server and my old tests which were giving me this error started working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I had installed the `xcuitest` driver in `package.json`.  When I uninstalled the driver and installed it in the global appium, the code 65 error disappeared and my tests started working again.